# Not Found HTTP Exception - in Laravel & How to reset password using own method

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, token

I am trying to implement reset password functionality but i am getting error not found http exception and i want to implement my own method of password reset but i am using laravel own functionality but i am unable to solve this solution 
i am also attaching my screen shot:[image]

My Controller:

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
    * Create a new password controller instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    public function getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse()
    {
        return View::make('auth.passwordSent');
    }
    protected $redirectPath = '/';
 }
```

My Form:

```
<form action="/password/reset" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login-form-email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" tabindex="1" placeholder="Email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login-form-password">New password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="login-form-password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" tabindex="4">
    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login-form-password-retype">Confirm new password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" id="login-form-password-retype" tabindex="3" placeholder="Confirm password">
    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="reset-confirm" id="reset-confirm" tabindex="4" value="Reset Password">
    </div>
</form>
```

And my page view page of email when i got email:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome Email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello {{$user['first_name']}}</h2>
        <br/>
        You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.
        <br/>
        <a href="{{url('/password/reset', $user->reset_token)}}">Reset 
        Password</a>
        <br />
        <p>If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.<br />Regards,<br /><strong>Triple R Lense</strong></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my routes:

```
 Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
 Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Your help will be highly appreciated?

Comment: Hello mate, where is your ***virtual host***? Where is your ***public***? How you are running laravel without ***serving to run project***? Can you please go through this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation) ***carefully*** ?